# Proving $x^2+x$ uniformly continuous in (0,1) using $\epsilon, \delta$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $x^2+x$ is uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$ using the $\epsilon , \delta$ method.
My try:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}3$. Then pick $x,y\in(0,1)$ s.t. $|x-y|<\delta$, so we have $|x^2+x-y^2-y|=|(x^2-y^2)+(x-y)|\leq|x^2-y^2|+|x-y|.$

Note that $|x^2-y^2|=|(x-y)(x+y)|$ and $x,y\in(0,1)$ so $(x+y)>0$$\space$ and $<2$.
So it's equal to $|x-y|(x+y)<2\delta$.

Coming back we have: $|x^2-y^2|+|x-y|=|x-y|(x+y)+|x-y|<3\delta=\epsilon.$

It's this okay? How could I write it better? Am I wrong somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Your argument is OK and I think you've written it as well as possible already.

Comment: That is, x(x+1) is uniformly continuous. It is suffficient to show that the product of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Alephnull But it's not possible to show that (unless you also assume the two functions are bounded, or something along those lines).  For example, $f(x) = g(x) = x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but their product isn't.

Comment: It is well-known that x^2 is uniformly continuous. You can use the same delta (or is it epsilon?) .

Comment: x^2+x is between x^2 and (x+1)^2 . It is well-known x^2 is  uniformlycontinuous and thus by graph-similarity (x+1)^2 is uniformly continuous. Thus x^2+x is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The same result can be obtained in a easier way by using  the Mean Value Theorem: if $f(x)=x^2+x$ then for $x,y\in (0,1)$ there is $t\in (0,1)$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(t)||x-y|=|2t+1||x-y|\leq 3|x-y|.$$
More generally a differentiable function whose derivative is bounded in an interval $I$ is also uniformly continuous in $I$.

Comment: @MayureshL Here we are talking about **uniform** continuity.

Comment: Robert.Gives the result from a different angle.Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine. A shortcut would be to note that $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$, and so uniformly continuous there; hence, on $(0,1),$ too.